Cannot ping other node's clusterIP within kubernetes cluster
I have setup a small microk8s cluster, for now only consisting of 2 machines (1 master, 1 worker).
I can successfully ping both machines on their internal IP, but any pod running on the other cluster cannot be contacted via the Cluster IP. Consider the following pod in the State Running:
Name:             whoami-b577bd888-lw465
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             rpi001/10.0.0.142
Start Time:       Fri, 06 Sep 2024 22:11:31 +0200
Labels:           app=whoami
                  pod-template-hash=b577bd888
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 9e113afb4361315cbc6a3d31293c2267f4c633f4fee95314e0d98d3fda2d24fc
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.1.191.66/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.1.191.66/32
Status:           Running
IP:               10.1.191.66
IPs:
  IP:           10.1.191.66
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/whoami-b577bd888
Containers:
  whoami:
    Container ID:   containerd://3e1965112785da0989b7cf39f6c94cbde2228c508bb27cb6763af6763848e07b
    Image:          containous/whoami
    Image ID:       docker.io/containous/whoami@sha256:7d6a3c8f91470a23ef380320609ee6e69ac68d20bc804f3a1c6065fb56cfa34e
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 06 Sep 2024 22:11:56 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-jskpc (ro)
Conditions:
  Type                        Status
  PodReadyToStartContainers   True
  Initialized                 True
  Ready                       True
  ContainersReady             True
  PodScheduled                True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-jskpc:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>

Being on master:
main@localhost:~$ ping rpi001
PING rpi001.home (10.0.0.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from rpi001.home (10.0.0.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.632 ms
64 bytes from rpi001.home (10.0.0.142): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.537 ms

ping 10.1.191.66 does not deliver any results. Is this intentional? I added a worker node using the microk8s join command with the --worker flag.
main@localhost:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME        STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
localhost   Ready    <none>   42h   v1.30.4
rpi001      Ready    <none>   36h   v1.30.4

rpi001@rpi001:~ $ microk8s status
This MicroK8s deployment is acting as a node in a cluster.
Please use the control plane node

The pod can be reached from the worker node though:
rpi001@rpi001:~ $ ping 10.1.191.66
PING 10.1.191.66 (10.1.191.66) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.1.191.66: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.277 ms

I followed this tutorial which does not mention any other steps. So the question is: is the separation of nodes by design? Would it be good practive to add some IP routing to enable this? If yes, how should this de done?
The reason for my question: if the cluster nodes cannot communicate with each others' pods, how should an ingress controller managing incoming traffic from outside the cluster work?
